# Export multiple Tables from Excel to a template Word document using VBA/Apache POI

Tags: java, vba, excel, apache-poi

So I have this macro, which can copy a single table from an Excel sheet to a template Word document. How do I modify it, so it can copy let's say 6 tables from 6 different Excel sheets into a template Word document?  Or can I achieve this with Apache POI API to copy multiple tables from Excel to Word??

```
Sub ExportDataToWord()
  Worksheets("Val Balance Sheet").Range("A1:D22").Copy
  Dim wdapp, wddoc As Object

  Dim strdocname As String
  On Error Resume Next
  Set wdapp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
  If Err.Number = 429 Then
    Err.Clear
    Set wdapp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
  End If

  wdapp.Visible = True
  strdocname = "C:\Users\ako\report.docx"
  If Dir(strdocname) = "" Then
    MsgBox "The file " & strdocname & vbCrLf & "was not found " & vbCrLf & "C:\Users\ako\.", vbExclamation, "The document does not exist."
    Exit Sub
  End If

  wdapp.Activate
  Set wddoc = wdapp.documents.Open(strdocname)
  If wddoc Is Nothing Then Set wddoc = wdapp.DocumentOpen(strdocnme)
  wddoc.Activate
  wddoc.Range.Paste
  wddoc.Save
  wdapp.Quit

  Set wddoc = Nothing
  Set wdapp = Nothing
  Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

Heres an update to what I was now trying, but it is only pasting the second table into word Template? What needs to be modified here to allow it to paste the multiple words without overwriting the first table.

```
 Sub ExportToWord()

 Worksheets("Val Balance Sheet").Range("A1:D22").Copy
 Dim wdapp, wddoc As Object

 Dim strdocname As String
 On Error Resume Next
 Set wdapp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
 If Err.Number = 429 Then Err.Clear
 Set wdapp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
 End If

 wdapp.Visible = True
 strdocname = "C:\Users\ako\report.docx"
 If Dir(strdocname) = "" Then
MsgBox "The file " & strdocname & vbCrLf & "was not found " & vbCrLf & "C:\Users\ako\.", vbExclamation, "The document does not exist."
 Exit Sub
 End If

 wdapp.Activate
 Set wddoc = wdapp.documents.Open(strdocname)
 If wddoc Is Nothing Then Set wddoc = wdapp.DocumentOpen(strdocnme)
 wddoc.Activate
 wddoc.Range.Paste


 Worksheets("Template Gains and Losses").Range("A1:C11").Copy
 Dim wdapp2, wddoc2 As Object

 Dim strdocname2 As String
 On Error Resume Next
 Set wdapp2 = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
 If Err.Number = 429 Then
 Err.Clear
 Set wdapp2 = CreateObject("Word.Application")
 End If

 wdapp2.Visible = True
 strdocname2 = "C:\Users\ako\report.docx"
 If Dir(strdocname2) = "" Then
 MsgBox "The file " & strdocname2 & vbCrLf & "was not found " & vbCrLf & "C:\Users\ako\.", vbExclamation, "The document does not exist."
 Exit Sub
 End If

 wdapp2.Activate
 Set wddoc2 = wdapp.documents.Open(strdocname)
 If wddoc2 Is Nothing Then Set wddoc2 = wdapp2.DocumentOpen(strdocnme2)
 wddoc2.Activate
 wddoc2.Range.Paste


 wddoc.Save
 wdapp.Quit

 Set wddoc = Nothing
 Set wdapp = Nothing
 Application.CutCopyMode = False

 End Sub
```

Comment: Up at the top, where it says to copy the range (your table) until it says wddoc.range.paste, is the meat of this.  If you add in additional copy/pastes before the .save and .quit lines, you should be fine to keep adding to the word doc.  Just make sure to add a paragraph between tables, or you will have them all run together.

Comment: @Cyril I have tried what you said. but now it is overwriting the first table, and just pasting the second table alone, how do i make it paste all tables in the word Template? please see my updated code of what i was trying.

Comment: You would need to attest to the word range, and add a paragraph after each table, Paragraphs.Add function.  The subsequent tables would be added after the paragraph (end of document).  If this causes more coding problems, you can take your copied text, activate the word doc, then selection.endkey unit:=wdstory, and place your text (if .paste fails, .insert should be backup plan).